# A condition for a Toeplitz operator to be Fredholm and find its index

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

I have a question about showing that a Toeplitz operator is Fredholm:

> Show that the operator $T_{e^{inx}}:L_2^+\to L_2^+$ acting on $L_2^+=\sum_{k\ge
> 0}a_ke^{ikx}$ with $\sum_{k}|a_k|^2<\infty$ is Fredholm for every
> $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ and find its index.

Denote $S^1$ to be the unit circle. The space $L_2^+$ is space of functions $f(z)$ on $S^1$ with $z=e^{i\theta}$ $$f(z)=\sum_{n\ge 0}a_nz^n$$ with norm $$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}|f(e^{i\theta})|^2d\theta=\sum_{n\ge 0}|a_n|^2$$

$P^+$ is the projection from $L_2(\mathbb{Z})$ onto $L_2^+$, $\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}a_ke^{ikx}\mapsto\sum_{k\ge
0}a_ke^{ikx}$. If $h(e^{i\theta})$ is a bounded function on $S^1$, $T_h:L_2^+\to L_2^+$ is defined as $$T_h(f)=P^+hf$$
and $\|T_h\|\leq\sup_{\theta}|h(\theta)|$

I'm trying to show that this Toeplitz operator is Fredholm and find its index. My attempt is to show the following: if $h$ is a continuous mapping from $S^1$ to $\mathbb{C}$ and $h(z)\neq 0$ on $S^1$, then $T_h$ is Fredholm. Once I have this, how can apply this to $T_{e^{inx}}$? **Added:** This works.

For the index, I have read from various sources that $\text{ind}(T_h)=-w(h)$, the winding number of $h$. Is it true for my case? **Added:** It is $-n$ by computing the winding number of $e^{inx}$ directly.

Thank you.

**Added:** if $h$ is a continuous mapping from $S^1$ to $\mathbb{C}$ and $h(z)\neq 0$ on $S^1$, then $T_h$ is Fredholm.
The theorem I used can be proved by:

If $h_1$ and $h_2$ are continuous, $T_{h_1}T_{h_2}-T_{h_1h_2}$ is compact.

Comment: @Aweygan I have made some edits.

Answer (score 2):

It is true that for $h\in C(S^1)$, the Toeplitz operator $T_h$ is Fredholm if and only if $0$ is not in the range of $h$, and that $\operatorname{ind}(T_h)=-\operatorname{wind}(h)$.  However, this using this result to compute $\operatorname{ind}(T_{e^{inx}})$ is both unnecessary (the index can be computed directly from the definition) and circular (to prove the above index theorem, one reduces to the case that $h=e^{inx}$ for some $n$, then computes $\operatorname{ind}(T_{e^{inx}})=-n$).

In any case, one only needs to compute the index of $T_{e^{ix}}$.  Note that this operator is an isometry, so $\ker(T_{e^{inx}})=\{0\}$.  Also, $T_{e^{-ix}}=(T_{e^{ix}})^*$ has a one-dimensional kernel spanned by the constant functions, and therefore $$\operatorname{ind}(T_{e^{ix}})=\dim\ker(T_{e^{ix}})-\dim\ker(T_{e^{-ix}})=-1.$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer. How can I prove that $T_h$ is Fredholm iff $0\notin\text{Ran}(h)$? The theorem I used is from my class, but without a proof.

Comment: The proof requires several lemmas.  The forward direction is shown by observing that $\mathbb K(L^+_2)$, the compact operators on $L_2^+$, is an ideal in the $C^*$-algebra $\mathcal T$ generated by the Toeplitz operators, and $\mathcal T/\mathbb K(L^+_2)\cong C(S^1)$, with the quotient map taking $T_h$ to $h$.

Comment: For the reverse direction, one simply needs show that for $f,h\in C(S^1)$, the operator $T_fT_h-T_{fh}$ is compact.  Then if $0\notin\operatorname{Ran}(h)$, taking $f=h^{-1}$ shows us that $T_h$ is Fredholm.